# Opencart Undefined in model file?

Tags: php, opencart

Hey Guys I am trying to pass data to my model, but for some reason I keep getting an "undefined customitem_id" in my model file. I am testing to see if it will even send to the model so:

the code is as follows. My controller file from customer.php file

```
        $data['customitem_id']= 19;
        if(isset($this->request->post['customitem_id'])) {
        $this->request->post['customitem_id'];
        }
```

My code from:

```
public function editCustomer($customer_id, $data) {
        if (!isset($data['custom_field'])) {
            $data['custom_field'] = array();
        }


        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET customer_group_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_group_id'] . "', sales_representative = '" . $this->db->escape($data['username']) . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', custom_field = '" . $this->db->escape(isset($data['custom_field']) ? serialize($data['custom_field']) : '') . "', newsletter = '" . (int)$data['newsletter'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', approved = '" . (int)$data['approved'] . "', safe = '" . (int)$data['safe'] . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");


        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "custom_item SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' WHERE customitem_id = '" . (int)$customitem_id . "'");
```

it keeps giving me an undefined variable in the model file. How would I go about making sure it sends the data?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing an array `$data` to your `editCustomer($customer_id, $data)` right?

Try changing this from:

```
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "custom_item SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' WHERE customitem_id = '" . (int)$customitem_id . "'")
```

to

```
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "custom_item SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' WHERE customitem_id = '" . (int)$data['customitem_id'] . "'")
```

note that I changed `(int)$customitem_id` to `(int)$data['customitem_id']`

Answer (score 0):

You're using variable $customitem_id in your model but in your controller it is $data['customitem_id']. You likely just need to change $customitem_id to $data['customitem_id'] in your model.